# A file is divided into pieces and sent to the client out of hub in signalr core

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

SignalR uses per-connection buffers to manage incoming and outgoing messages. By default, SignalR limits these buffers to 32 KB. The largest message a client or server can send is 32 KB. The maximum memory consumed by a connection for messages is 32 KB. If your messages are always smaller than 32 KB, you can reduce the limit, which:
Prevents a client from being able to send a larger message.
The server will never need to allocate large buffers to accept messages.
If your messages are larger than 32 KB, you can increase the limit. Increasing this limit means:
The client can cause the server to allocate large memory buffers.
Server allocation of large buffers may reduce the number of concurrent connections.
There are limits for incoming and outgoing messages, both can be configured on the HttpConnectionDispatcherOptions object configured in MapHub:
ApplicationMaxBufferSize represents the maximum number of bytes from the client that the server buffers. If the client attempts to send a message larger than this limit, the connection may be closed.
TransportMaxBufferSize represents the maximum number of bytes the server can send. If the server attempts to send a message (including return values from hub methods) larger than this limit, an exception will be thrown.
Setting the limit to 0 disables the limit. Removing the limit allows a client to send a message of any size. Malicious clients sending large messages can cause excess memory to be allocated. Excess memory usage can significantly reduce the number of concurrent connections.

but i don't want that.

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: Either bad spam or a badly asked question! https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/signalr/security.md#buffer-management